# CSS :not pseudo-class applying broadly and not targeting specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am learning about the `:not()` pseudo class and it is not working as expected.

I want to color all text red except for `.mind`. For some reason this is not preventing the `.mind` element from being red.

```css
:not(.mind) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep this in mind:

`:not()` is equivalent to `*:not()`

When there is no selector prefixing the `:not()` pseudo-class, a universal selector is implied:

> [**6.2. Universal
> selector**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#universal-selector)
>
> If a universal selector represented by `*` (i.e. without a namespace
> prefix) is not the only component of a sequence of simple selectors
> selectors or is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the `*`
> may be omitted and the universal selector's presence implied.

Therefore, the rule you have:

```
:not(.mind) {
  color: red
}
```

... is saying *apply red color to all elements except the element with the class `mind`.*

Okay, except in this case, [the `color` property is inheritable](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#propdef-color), so even though the red doesn't get applied to the `.mind` element, it still gets the red through inheritance from the  `.parent` element.

Here's what the browser is doing:

[image]

A quick way to test this behavior is with the `border` property, which is not inheritable.

In the example below, using your selector, you'll notice that the border doesn't get applied to `.mind`, and your selector works as you were expecting:

```css
:not(.mind) {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To your particular objective:

> I want to color all text red except for `.mind`.

Use a more specific selector.

```
.parent > :not(.mind) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.parent > :not(.mind) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would also work:

```
div.child:not(.mind) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
div.child:not(.mind) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Another comment repost](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/66825737): "In my experience, most authors find it surprising that a pseudo-class or pseudo-element can appear by itself, without an accompany [sic] type, id or class selector. And when you tell them that a pseudo-class or pseudo-elt can appear by itself in much the same way an id or class selector can, they act like they just had an epiphany. All this because you rarely find lone pseudo-classes or pseudo-elts in production CSS (other than :root and ::selection I guess)."

Comment: You can report typos to www-style, but since css3-selectors is already a REC, and selectors-4 is actively being worked on, I wouldn't bother. There are a number of others, like "occurrances" in the specificity section.

Comment: Great answer thank you. I was going crazy trying to figure out why `.foo :not(.bar)` was resulting in `.bar` having the rule applied - inheritance!

Answer (score 3):

your selector works fine, because `:not(.mind)` is the same as `*:not(.mind)` - which is a universal selector -  **but** because `.mind` is child of `.parent` it will get `color:red` inherited from `.parent`, and that's why you see it colored red.

To simplify, in this case no need to use `:not()` just use `.child`

```css
.child {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However if you want the `.mind` div to have also `.child` class, in that case, you can use `:not()` like this:

```
.child:not(.mind) {rules}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.child:not(.mind) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Currently I am learning about the `:not()` pseudo-class and would like to know why my code did not work.

Comment: `div:not(.mind)` as an example selector will make much more sense here.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the syntax on MDN and it does not require a modifier like `.child` at the beginning of `not()`. It states the syntax to be `:not( <selector># ) { style properties }`. i think that's what confused me. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: @Mr.Alien it would, but then the `color:red` in `.parent` is inherited by `.mind`, therefore `.mind` will be red https://jsfiddle.net/6rh873zz/

Comment: @dippas agreed. Just to have a clear example. We can use other property which might not be inherited.

Comment: @Mr.Alien well I didn't want to change the OP selectors/markup, but yes I understand your POV ;)

Comment: @dippas you already changed it by calling two classes on one element :)

Comment: @Robert Rocha: :not() doesn't *need* to be qualified by any other selector, it just works in a different and surprising manner due to its nature, and that's why most people recommend qualifying it with another selector (although they erroneously say that it's *invalid* to leave a :not() selector unqualified).

Answer (score 0):

It's targeting the parent selector, and the child (.mind) is inheriting it. The code works just fine if `.mind` doesn't inherit a color from the parent.

```css
div:not(.mind) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='child'>Two</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'>One</div>
  <div class='mind'>mind</div>
  <div class='child'>Three</div>
  <div class='child'><p>First paragraph</p></div>
```

You'll need to define rules for `.mind` specifically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use   `:not` As follows :

```
.parent :not(.mind){
    color:red;
}
```

Code :

```css
.parent :not(.mind){
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='child'>One</div>
 <div class='child'>Two</div>
 <div class='child'>Three</div>
 <div class='child'>One</div>
 <div class='child'>Two</div>
 <div class='child'>Three</div>
 <div class='child'>One</div>
     
 <div class='mind'>mind</div>
     
 <div class='child'>Three</div>
 <div class='child'>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
 </div>
</div>
```