# first-child and a list within a list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the first-child in a parent list:

```css
ol:first-child > li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Numbered list item 1</li>
  <li>Numbered list item 2
    <ol>
      <li>sublist item 1</li>
      <li>sublist item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Numbered list item 3</li>
</ol>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cvuw2bd1/1/

not the sublist. But if I close second list item before starting the sublist it works.

```
<li>Numbered list item 2</li>
<ol>...
```

As shown here:

```css
ol:first-child > li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Numbered list item 1</li>
  <li>Numbered list item 2</li>
  <ol>
    <li>sublist item 1</li>
    <li>sublist item 2</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Numbered list item 3</li>
</ol>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cvuw2bd1/

Unfortunately, I can't change the HTML only the CSS. Is there a way around this so that the sublist is excluded in the first example. (I can't add any classes or ids.)

Comment: What about using `ol > li:first-child` and then resetting `ol ol > li:first-child`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [applying css for only parent but not to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787178/applying-css-for-only-parent-but-not-to-children)

Comment: @lumio it's not duplicate because it's about inheritance here .. actually he's selecting only the needed elements

Comment: Even if you could change the html the second example html you have is invalid html

Comment: Could you please clarify: are you trying to select the "the first-child *in* a parent list" (as the question says) or the list that *is* the first child in *its* parent (as the code, including the "working" example, implies)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ol` you are targeting with `ol:first-child > li` is the first, last and only child in the HTML structure. It has no siblings. The same goes for the nested `ol`.

The `ol` elements have vertical (ancestor-descendant), not lateral (sibling), relationships.

So don't use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-classes. Use [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

```css
li {
  color: red;
}

li li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Numbered list item 1</li>
  <li>Numbered list item 2
    <ol>
      <li>sublist item 1</li>
      <li>sublist item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Numbered list item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Also, when dealing with the `color` property, it's important to be familiar with the concept of **inheritance**. Here's an explanation:

- [CSS :not pseudo-class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41604369/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style to the child element of `li` if you can not change the html

```css
ol:first-child > li {
  color: red;
}
li li{
  color:black !important;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Numbered list item 1</li>
  <li>Numbered list item 2
    <ol>
      <li>sublist item 1</li>
      <li>sublist item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Numbered list item 3</li>
</ol>
```

last but not the least... If it does not work use `important`